Are there any free modern images similar to the "blue marble" pictures from 2004
NASA published these incredibly nice pictures of the earth called Blue Marble NG like https://neo.gsfc.nasa.gov/archive/bluemarble/bmng/world_8km/world.topo.bathy.200412.3x5400x2700.png
However I am not able to find anything more current than 2004.
Are there no publicly accessible more modern images, or am I just searching wrong?
I was expecting more modern images to possibly reflect some changes like less ice in the north&south.
